# Problem with loading CSS while invoking page by Server.Transfer()

Tags: c#, asp.net

While I'm using *Response.Redirect("~/Pages/Page.aspx")*, style is loaded on the page, but unfortunately it is not loaded while I'm using *Server.Transfer("~/Pages/Page.aspx")* method.

The page looks following:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
   <link href="../Css/Layout/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

How to make the page load **style.css** using Server.Transfer() ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use a relative path to your CSS file, you should use an abolute path.

If the css folder is inside your application root, you can use

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
   <link href="/Css/Layout/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

or even

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
   <link href="~/Css/Layout/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" ID="aUniqueId" />
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you tell us 1. what is the absolute path (with host name) of the page that you are transferring from and 2. what is the path (with host name) of the css folder.

Comment: Actually I realized, that the source of the problem is a bit more weird, so I've created new thread for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896203/application-error-exceptions-handling-redirection-infinite-loop-and-css-loading