# Application_Error exceptions handling, redirection infinite loop and CSS loading problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have error handling in Application_Error event of globals.asax file. Inside this event, I'm using `Response.Redirect(~errorview.aspx)` method, for redirection to site which is able to handle errors in user friendly way.

Everything works fine, unless exception is rising in Application_Start event. When error occurs there, my application gets trapped in infinite loop with the Application_Error method hit repeatedly. What is more, the page I'm redirecting to never gets hit. Changing `Response.Redirect(~errorview.aspx)` method to `Response.Redirect(~errorview.aspx, false)` changes nothing.

The good news is, when `Response.Redirect(~errorview.aspx)` has been replaced with `Server.Transfer(~errorview.aspx)`, errorview.aspx page succesfully gets hit.

The side effect now is not loading CSS, and errorview.aspx page looks ugly. What is more, the CSS is not loaded **only** when exception occurs in **Application_Start** event. Exceptions thrown from any other place don't make the CSS mess.

How I can handle this problem in correct way, and why the CSS is missing in the one particular situation ? What is the appropriate way of handling errors in my case ?

**UPDATE**

For CSS loading, I'm using this:

```
<link href="~/Css/Layout/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
      runat="server" ID="_uid" />
```

error page I'm transfering from: **http://localhost/APP/Pages/Module/Pages/ErrorView.aspx**

css folder path: **http://localhost/APP/Pages/Module/CSS/Layout/style.css**

Thanks for any clues in advance. Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting exceptions during Application_Start, you have bigger problems than trying to get CSS to load in the error page.  Application_Start is intended as a bootstrapper for the Web site to initialize everything.  If you can't successfully initialize the application, you probably won't be able to service any requests.  (You shouldn't be publishing an application to a production environment when it is known to have exceptions in the Application_Start anyway.)

Ultimately, what Server.Transfer is doing is simply switching from processing the current path to processing the new path.  The request context is not modified, so any relative references in the new path are relative to the *original* request.  If an exception happens in Application_Start, there is no original request.  (Requests aren't handled by Application_Start.  A request can cause Application_Start to be invoked, but it won't know anything about the request.)  That's probably why Server.Transfer from an Application_Start exception doesn't load the CSS - there's no original request context.

Also, it's generally a better idea to have a static html-only error page.  If there's an error caused by some ASP.NET processing in IIS, then it's likely that an error page that is also processed by the ASP.NET will suffer the same error, possibly causing an infinite loop (the error page redirects to the error page because there was an error - lather, rinse, repeat).  (This is the infinite loop situation that you experienced.)  Eventually, good browsers will notice this and stop the loop, but you still have the runaway request cycle.  If you use a static html-only page, then you prevent ASP.NET from ever attempting to process the request.  (It's usually cleaner, too, as you should have a very simple, straightforward error page that displays to the visitor and have all the error trapping and notifications handled behind the scenes.)

Comment: I wanted to add a little bit to this - something that can cause confusion at first glance.  When you use Server.Transfer, it doesn't start a new Response.  If you've written anything to the Response (for example, if the error occurs midway through generating the output for the page), then you'll get your new page rendered within that context.  If you want to make sure that your error page is the only thing rendered to the browser, you'll want to call Response.Clear *before* calling Server.Transfer.  (One of the other answers below mentions this briefly.)

Comment: i found this explanation(use of static pages) very useful..:)